# how to eliminate duplicate's documents while searching in elasticsearch search server

Tags: elasticsearch

>
Is there any technique To eliminate duplicate documents while search in elastic-search.how to compare the values among the different documents in the search results.is any script    available.
>

Comment: I hope this helped, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [More Like This API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html) to look for documents that match a specified documents field values. Some customization maybe required.

Comment: sorry this is not compatible for my requirements i need to filter a document based on (ex: title field )but no two documents title should not same in the resulted document.

Comment: So you need to exclude duplicate documents on specific fields?

Comment: It is hard for me to understand your problem with such little explanation. I understand that you want to remove duplicate document results. But, say you have 20 documents with a title of "foo", do you want to just remove 19 documents with title of "foo"? Are you doing a query that scores another field on the documents? Do you want a document with a certain timestamp over another?

Comment: sorry for that little example, i can explain from your explanation when you search "foo" if that term matches (20 documents) the resulted    documents title should not same it has to be unique, even that document indexed twice.